# Help deriving a probability

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Let's say I have 6 balls and 3 containers which are initially empty (A, B, and C).

If the 6 balls are distributed randomly across the 3 containers, what is the probability that a specific container (let's say A, though it doesn't matter which one) will end up with 2 or more balls?

More generally, what's the solution with n1 balls, n2 containers and a threshold of n3?

I took a probability course at university, but that was a while ago--can you help me derive the solution?

Comment: Do you suppose, that every single ball has the same probability to go into every container?

Comment: Yes - thank you

Comment: Are all the balls identical?

Answer (score 2):

The probability, that no ball goes into the container $A$ is $(\frac{2}{3})^6$.
Now, name the balls giving them numbers as name. The probability that the #1 ball is the only, which goes into the container $A$ is $\frac{1}{3}(\frac{2}{3})^5$. It means that probability that the #1 or #2 or ... #6 ball is the only, which goes into the container $A$ is $6\cdot\frac{1}{3}(\frac{2}{3})^5$.
That is, the probability that at least two balls go into $A$ is 
$$1-\left(\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^6+6\cdot\frac{1}{3}\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^5\right).$$
Well, I think, this is a hint for the general problem too.

Comment: So if I wanted to calculate the probability of 3 or more balls in A, the third term in parenthesis would be: (6 choose 2)*(1/3)^2*(2/3)^4, is that right?

Comment: Yes, it is. Perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

It is usually best to answer a question like "$2$ or more" by finding the probability of $0$ or $1$ and then taking the complement. The probability of having 0 balls in $A$ is $\frac{2}{3}^6$ because for each ball there is a $\frac{2}{3}$ chance that it is not going into $A$ and since each ball is independent we can multiply these probabilities together $6$ times to get $P(\mbox{0 in A})=(\frac{2}{3})^6$. Maybe you can figure out how to find out $P(\mbox{1 in A})=$?

Comment: P(1 in A) would be (1/3)*(2/3)^5, so P(2 or more) would be 1 - [P(0)+P(1)-P(0)P(1)], correct?

Comment: It should just be $1-P(0)-P(1)$ since $P(1)$ and $P(0)$ are mutually exclusive.